# Removing ID from CakePHP URL?

Tags: php, cakephp

Hey guys! Working on a new Cake app and wondering if there is anyway for me to remove the ID-in-URL routing from Cake. Perhaps by passing the ID in POST somehow? Having the ID passed in as a URL param just seems really shoddy and unsafe. Thanks!

Comment: No, seriously… **"shoddy"**?!

Comment: @deceze: [I'm sorry for this link :)](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%3Ashoddy). In this context "shoddy" = "an inferior method".

Comment: @thirtydot I know what "shoddy" means, thank you very much. :o) I just can't get over the fact that it is used in this context. Also, "inferior" to what alternative?

Comment: @deceze: I commented because you seemed *so surprised* at the usage of the word, whereas I wouldn't have even thought twice about it (as a native English speaker). "inferior" to some imaginary better method the question asker was looking for.

Comment: @thirtydot Well, I'd really like to hear to line of reasoning that lead to the use of the word in this context. I can't wrap my head around it… ;o)

Comment: @deceze: Perhaps a question for http://english.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @thirtydot No, a question of "what were you thinking?!" =)

Answer (score 2):

"Shoddy"? It's standard practice and a perfectly fine solution to have ids in the URL. Look at the URL of your question:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638262/removing-id-from-cakephp-url
                                   ^^^^^^^
                                      id
```

Also, there's absolutely nothing unsafe about showing an id in a URL. It's just a number that doesn't mean anything. If a user can do something "bad" only by knowing this id, **your app** is broken and insecure, not the id-passing mechanism.

Trying to work around this scheme means working around the fundamental principle of the HTML protocol and opens up a whole new can of worms.

Comment: Also, passing the id as a POST parameter isn't any more secure. If someone can't find the id from the POST parameters it's a pretty safe bet to say that they don't have the skills to hack the site.

Answer (score 1):

Some people prefer using *slugs* instead of primary key ids. This is the `removing-id-from-cakephp-url` part of the URL from this page. Take a look at the [SluggableBehavior](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/mariano/2007/03/24/sluggable-behavior).

However, slugs *can* change. Hence, having the primary key in your URL is useful if you want to have a permalink. StackOverflow does both so that it can support both permalinking from other sites, as well as for SEO reasons. :)

Regarding security issues, I guess the other answers have already pointed out that there are other ways to make your application secure.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you care? URL-s are optimized for SEO reasons, an ID won't matter if it's ain't too long. If the latter, consider using a shorter one with numbers and letters in them instead, it will be as difficult to guess as a long one with just numbers.

If you are not using GET and you do not supply the params in the URL, your users won't be able to copy-paste the location.