# Removing ids from url

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, routes

I want to rewrite urls in cakephp. I have used the routes.php class for this purpose.I have used the following code:

```
//Routes.php
Router::connect(
    '/:slug-:id', 
    array('controller' => 'Products', 'action' => 'product_listing'), 
    array('pass' => array('id', 'slug'))
);
//header.php
<?php echo $this->Html->link(
  $sub['category_name'],
  array(
      'controller' => 'Products',
      'action' => 'product_listing',
      'slug' => Inflector::slug($sub['category_name'],'-'),
      'id' => base64_encode(convert_uuencode($sub['id']))
  )
);?>
```

Everything is working fine but my client is saying that id should not view in the url. Please anyone help me to remove id from urls.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! There are already many questions regarding this - [Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638262/removing-id-from-cakephp-url) or [even look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17506287/want-to-remove-action-name-from-url-cakephp). There are many more. They may prove to be helpful.

Comment: Yes I have already searched for this on google as well as viewed the topics of stackoverflow.com related to this as well. But I haven't find solution of my problem anywhere.

Comment: What URL do you expect to be generated by HtmlHelper?

Comment: You need to edit your question, and add detail to why those other SO answers do not meet your need.

Comment: @bancer My url is something like this http://primemart.in/Smart-Phones-Ii4zJGAKYAo= and i want to remove id from url.

Comment: @AgRizzo For the detail I would have to ask from my client and i will let u know later that why my client needs to remove id from url.

Comment: 1) Why does your client want to remove id? 2) How do you expect the server to decide which product you have requested if you do not pass the id to the server?